# C++ Memory management by returning a pointer to a simple type

Tags: c++, memory-management

i want to ask about the following situation

```
int * foo() {
    int fooint = 5;
    return &fooint;
}

int myint = *foo();
```

its based on
http://www.functionx.com/cpp/examples/returnpointer.htm

but i want to ask, if it is safe, because what i think will happen

- fooint gets initialized in the scope of foo()
- the address of fooint is returned and foo() ends
- all variables in foo() gets destroyed
- so myint will hold the value, of an int at destroyed adress

wouldn't it be better to do

```
int * foo() {
    int * fooint = new int;
    *fooint = 5;
    return fount;
}

int * tmp = foo();
int myint = * tmp;
delete tmp;
```

Comment: I strongly suggest forgetting about that "tutorial".

Comment: Yes, to be clear, that link to cpp examples is very bad advice.

Comment: If you do need to return complex types as a pointer consider wrapping them in an `auto_ptr`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you shouldn't ever return addresses of temporary variables exactly for the reasons you give. The second variant is okay.

However using dynamic memory allocation for built-in types will be very expensive. In case of built-in types it'll much cheaper to just return by value:

```
int function()
{
    return 5;
}
```

and it will also be less error-prone (no possibility for a memory leak for example).

Comment: In fact, for types that can fit in registers (basically any primitive type) and depending on your calling convention, it'd probably be *leaps and bounds* faster to return by value.

Comment: the thing is, that this is just a simplification, in my program i have a function, which returns (void *), and i know what will be returned, like respond(RETURN_RANDOM_INT), respond(RETURN_RANDOM_FLOAT), respond(RETURN_RANDOM_XCLASS) etc. so it can return anything, but i know what type it will be

Comment: @Peter That is "a bad idea" (tm) - if you are using void pointers, you are almost certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: i am doing communication between objects, and i dont wont to overflood the communication class with respondToMessageWithInt(_message), respondToMessageWithFloat(_message), respondToMessageWithClassXPtr(_message) etc... i have a single method, which returns a message with messageValueType and the value, which is void * (the messageValueType is just a safechceck, because i know, what will be returned)

Comment: @Peter, did you consider a union instead of `void*` inside your message structure? Unions, especially anonymous ones usually work well with messageValueType kind of thing. It would also eliminate the need to allocate primitive types on the heap. For non-primitive types your union may still contain a `void*` or something.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is spot on. I would strongly encourage you to stop reading that document.

Instead, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909323/what-are-good-online-resources-or-tutorials-to-learn-c

Answer (score 0):

The question is why do you want to return a pointer? The normal thing to do is to return a value:

```
int foo() {
    int fooint = 5;
    return fooint;
}
```

In general, you should avoid dynamic memory allocation with new wherever possible and instead  let the compiler manage things for you.

Comment: @Peter Not a good idea to post identical comments to different answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you should not return addresses of temporary variables, and neither should you new something in a function and then return it, expecting the caller to clean it up (unless, of course, it is wrapped in something such as `boost::shared_ptr`).

So, for non-POD types, your class will need to have a copy constructor for the temporary (and perhaps a move constructor if you're using C++0x for better performance).

Answer (score 0):

This will cause a common problem called [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

When you do not have memory management system such as Garbage Collection (or smart pointers) you should always ask count the references and use the `delete` instruction in proper locations at the right times, a general rule of thumb is to never share the address of stack variables in different scopes.